# java.lang.reflect.field getText when field is JTextfield

Tags: java, swing, reflection, jtextfield, gettext

I have a class with over 50 JTextfield they all contain text

How to get the text from all Textfield without calling the fields in the code again.

I tried:

```
    Field[] fields = getClass().getDeclaredFields();       
    for (Field field : fields) {        
        if (field.getName().contains("_") == true) {
            // .getText();
        }
    }
```

Then I must get the text from the fields but how to manage this??

Or have someone a better idea to the the values??

Comment: This is an extremely bad program design to say the least. Why not put the fields in a collection so that you can identify the ones you need to extract text from?

Comment: Your question suggests that this may in fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: @JonnyHenly: you're right, thank you! Still, why is he using reflection? Why is he putting so much importance on field names?

Comment: My programm must get all Strings of this fields later in a while-loop without calling all fields again... any ideas for this??

Comment: Abgebaumt: please tell and show more. There must be a better way than what you're doing. I'll bet $100 on this.

Comment: @Abgebaumt Thanks for the quick accept! I am glad I could help.

Comment: I have to give -1 for not telling more about your problem and your code despite multiple requests.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sry. I was at dinner. So i have a Class with over 50 JTextfields. I have to read every one and get the value (text) from it and print it out. Im searching for the best and fastest way to print all var without calling them in code again

Comment: @Abgebaumt: Again, please edit your question, and add this information to it as well as more about the 50 fields, how they're organized and displayed. This information is much too important to be buried in comments. Also reflection is neither clean **nor** is it fast, and is guaranteed to not be the best way. Also it is fragile and will break if you or someone else renames a field at a later date. Again, I can guarantee that a better solution exists. Since you mention **50** JTextFields, I have to wonder if a JTable wouldn't be better, but again can't say without more information.

Comment: Consider even showing a picture of your GUI as well.

Comment: Better?? @HovercraftFullOfEels. Posting gui is not nessesary

Comment: No, it's not necessary, but are the 50 fields within a grid of some sort? Do they all hold the same type of data? How are they arranged and what data do they hold?

Comment: They all contain string

Comment: ...............................never mind.

Comment: Do you have a better idea than my own

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, Abgebaumt, I updated my answer with a new proposition according to your update (more than 50 textfields to handle)

Comment: Thanks I will try it this afternoon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggested, a clean implementation separates the matter : grouping fields gather and performing a processing on them.
Especially, if grouping is performed by reflection.
The following code is more readable and maintainable.

```
public class MyComponent extends JFrame{
  List<JTextField> fields = new ArrayList(); 

  private JTextField textField1;
  private JTextField textField2;
  private JTextField textField3;

  public MyComponent(){
   textField1 = new JTextField ("");
   textField2 = new JTextField ("");
   textField3 = new JTextField ("");
   addTextFieldInList(textField1, textField2, textField3);
  }

  public void addTextFieldInList(JTextField fieldArgs...) {
    fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(fieldArgs));
  }

  public void iterateAllTextFields(){
    for (JTextField field : fields){
      String yourValue = field.getText();
    }    
}
```

---

UPDATE after the update of the question where it is specified that the processing handle more than over 50 **JTtextField**.

In this case, another solution that which I proposed could be more suitable.
Indeed, with a dozen of fields, risking to forget to add a JTextField in the list is not very probable but with over 50, we can understand that is a error-prone processing. Creating your custom JTextField is maybe a better alternative.
The idea is the following : extending the JTextField with a new class `JTextFieldWatched` and forcing `JTextFieldWatched` constructor with an additional parameter : a object which registers `JTextField` instances.

`JTextFieldWatched` which extends `JTextField` :

```
public class JTextFieldWatched extends JTextField{
  public JTextFieldWatched(String text, JTextFieldWatcher textFieldWatcher){
    super(text);
    if (textFieldWatcher==null){
      // force the constraint
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("textFieldWatcher is mandatory");
    }        
     textFieldWatcher.add(this);
  }
}
```

A class which registers `JTextfield` instances :

```
public class JTextFieldWatcher {
   List<JTextField> fields = new ArrayList(); 

   public void add(JTextField textField){
      fields.add(textField);
   }   

   public List<JTextField> getAllTextField(){
      return new ArrayList(fields);
   }
}
```

How to use these classes:

```
public class MyComponent extends JFrame{
  private JTextFieldWatcher fieldsWatcher = new JTextFieldWatcher();

  private JTextFieldWatched textField1;
  private JTextFieldWatched textField2;
  private JTextFieldWatched textField3;

  public MyComponent(){
   textField1 = new JTextFieldWatched ("",fieldsWatcher);
   textField2 = new JTextFieldWatched ("",fieldsWatcher);
   textField3 = new JTextFieldWatched ("",fieldsWatcher);
  }   

  public void iterateAllTextFields(){
    for (JTextField field : fieldsWatcher.getAllTextField()){
      String yourValue = field.getText();
    }    
  }
}
```

All code is written at the hand without IDE, so sorry if any mistake.

Comment: no, thanks to you. All questions must no necessarily be addressed in the way it was requested. Especially, if the way seems clumsy.

Comment: Normally I prefer to give that "other" answer myself (as there is always somebody giving the immediate" answer) ... but I am glad you made your suggestion as well!

Comment: @GhostCat, I know that. I wonder the same question sometimes : taking the time or not...

Comment: I tried it and it works perfect. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You can use reflection to figure the actual type of your fields, like:

```
Field[] fields = getClass().getDeclaredFields();       
for (Field field : fields) {  
    Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();
    if (fieldType.isAssignableFrom(JTextfield.class)) {
      JTextField jtf = (JTextField) field.get(owningobject);       
 ...
```

In other words:

1. You can check if the field "is" a JTextField (that is **much** better than relying on some convention that anything with "_" in its name is a textfield)
2. If so, you simply *get* the value of the field, and cast it to its real type ... and then, you got a JTextField object, and you can call the method of that class directly!

Please note: my code is meant to get you going - I didn't run it through the compiler or tested it. So, beware of typos. But it should be enough to  make your own experiments and help you making progress.

EDIT, regarding your question: all those reflection get/set methods require you *some object* to work on. Meaning: you need an **instance** of that class that you are "reflecting" on (unless you are talking about static fields). See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html) or [there](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/fields.html) for further reading.

A final word of **warning**; as there are **two** things you should know when using reflection:

1. Only use it when there is no other way to solve your problem. Never use it because it seems convenient, but because there is no other way to get what you need!
2. Only use it when you understand 100% of reflection. Thing is: it is **super easy** to get reflection **wrong**. And you only notice at runtime. You can easily spend hours writing reflection code and trying to get it to work; running from one subtle problem into the next one. Getting reflection code is **hard**. And more painful: a subtle change in the code that "is reflected" can *break* your reflection-using code; and you don't notice until running that code!

So, long story short, and given your question: you seem to **not** know much about reflection. In that sense: be really careful. And maybe re-think if there are other, non-reflecting ways to solve your problem!

Comment: Ghost: but while this works, is it clean, and doesn't this design have code smell to it?

Comment: Can you help me?? What to putin "owningobject"

Comment: I updated my answer. And hint: be patient around here. Yes, people are willing to help, but be assured: I saw your comment the first time. No need to repeatedly ask ...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Upon reading his comment, I came to the same conclusion and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ghost, thanks. @Abgebaumt: what is "owningobject"? And again, please tell us more about your problem space in an edit to your original question. Help ask a better question so that this site can get better answers.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *owningobject* is what **I** put in my example code to express ... that well, when you call field.get(), you need some object for that call.